# gdx parse layout files to object files

Tags: java, android, libgdx

we use libgdx for graphics rendering for our game on android. Seems like libgdx can drop support for layout files in the future. Disadvantages of using layout file is that it take longer to parse it. Advantages being it is very convenient to build UI using it instead of building UI in java files.

So I would like to know if there is a way to parse layout into serializable object files and load these object files in the game instead of layout files. This way if we can maintain a utility, using old gdx library which produces object files from layout files and upgrade gdx in out actual game.

edit : the layout files are of libgdx's not android's

Comment: Android XML layout files don't have much to do with LibGDX I'm afraid.

Comment: I was talking about the libgdx layout files

Comment: I've never heard of a LibGDX layout file.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any way to serialize your layout information with libgdx. You will likely need to write your own wrappers and somehow store this layout information, as I don't know of anyone who has done this. If you are using an old version of the library, which still has the tablelayout files, I'm not sure how easy it will be considering the amount of changes which has been made to libgdx since that time. The alternative is to re-write you files using the Java api, which you will likely need to do going forward.

I am not sure how you are still using the tablelayout ui files. They have been deprecated for over a year now and are not included with any of the latest releases of libgdx. If you want a more detailed explanation on what happened to the layout files you can look at this [post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2483). I do miss the layout files because of the extra bloat created by having to code the ui formatting. However, I also find you get much finer control over dynamic layouts by using the Java api.